# 8 port managed switch with good ACL capability?

Tags: switch

I'm trying to find an 8 port managed switch with good scope for defining ACLs. Beyond that, the spec is fairly well defined so it's mostly down to "who makes this spec cheapest and not abysmal quality" :)

The kinds of features I'm after will tend to imply other features will be there "automatically", so I don't need to spec everything - for example it's incredibly unlikely that a switch with ACLs and VLANs won't also have port mirroring, so I don't need to list that specifically.

But it's sometimes hard to figure which switches have decent ACL capability - as in, fairly full-scope permit/deny on a list of ports, IPs and ideally other protocol elements. For example, I can imagine some switch that allowed 3 rather limited rules, that wouldn't be what I'm after. But it's hard to list exactly what ACL capabilities I need, I'd have to read up on recommended models.

*Also some product lines, the 8 port versions don't have ACLs where all others in the range do have them, and that's often buried in small print.*

## Scenario

The scenario is a home LAN, so I don't need catalysts, but that said, some Cisco is surprisingly cheap second hand and I routinely buy previous-generation hardware second hand (EBay etc) rather than new.

Most of the spec I'm after is well established stuff, so it won't have changed for 5 - 10 years so older in good condition would be fine too. If it matters I'm in the UK.

## Essential features

- 8 port RJ-45 gigabit port switch *(prefer not 16, overkill for this)*
- 9k Jumbo frames
- VLAN's
- Port grouping
- Bridging
- 802.1X with RADIUS/TACACS+ or similar
- ACLs - sets of "permit/deny" rules that can be set on IP/Port (and ideally protocol) etc for each port or group
- MAC filtering
- Non-feeble backplane and buffer (I don't need 2Gb per port x 8 ports, but I'd like to have at least say 3 or 4    Gb/s possible across it)
- GUI web config
- Reputation of manufacturer to provide updates for an extended period as an enterprise would need (eg in case of future security issues/firmware bugs, and unlike many consumer oriented manufacturers, so I'm not left up a creek without a paddle!).

## Everything else

- No need for rack mounting - **smaller is better**
- Spanning/rapid spanning nice if possible, not essential
- QoS tags nice if possible, not essential
- No need for PoE
- No need for redundant PSU and don't mind internal v external PSU, or active v passive cooling (not mission critical or a heat-prone location)
- Most other stuff (Mac address count, buffer, backplane,mirroring, GB/s etc) will be fine on any model, so no need to spec it

Comment: I don't have a complete answer for you, but talking about Cisco products I believe the cheapest ones with those features would be on the sg200 family, but you need to confirm the details on them.